# Finding more than instance of data in a Text File

Tags: vba, excel

I am desperately trying to create a macro which will allow me to do the following:

1. Select a text file (different one everytime)
2. Look at the data and identify the first instance of key phrases such as "_ _Z_1_:_"
3. Then extract data following that phrase
4. Write it to Excel
5. Then identify the next instance of the key phrase
6. Extract data
7. Write to Excel

Any help much appreciated.

I'm really not sure how to do it. My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, Day As String, Zno As String, NetSales As String, Cash As String, Card As String, HotDrinks As String, ColdDrinks As String, Sweets As String, Crisps As String, VAT As String, NextZ As String

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

Dim bffr As String, p As Long
bffr = (myFile)
p = InStr(p + 1, bffr, "_ _Z_1_:_", vbTextCompare)
Do While CBool(p)

'_ _Z_1_:_ was found; process it based upon the starting position p

'see if there are other occurrences of _ _Z_1_:_
p = InStr(p + 1, bffr, "_ _Z_1_:_", vbTextCompare)
Loop

Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, textline
text = text & textline
Loop
Close #1

Day = InStr(text, "Welcome Bite")
Zno = InStr(text, "_ _Z_1_:_")
NetSales = InStr(text, "NET sales          ")
Cash = InStr(text, "CASH in ")
Card = InStr(text, "CREDIT in")
HotDrinks = InStr(text, "HOT DRINKS         ")
ColdDrinks = InStr(text, "COLD DRINKS       ")
Sweets = InStr(text, "Sweets             ")
Crisps = InStr(text, "Crisps             ")
VAT = InStr(text, "** Fixed Totaliser Period 1 Totals Reset")
NextZ = InStr(text, "_ _Z_1_:_")


Range("A1").Value = Mid(text, Day + 19, 18)
Range("A2").Value = Mid(text, Zno + 10, 8)
Range("A3").Value = Mid(text, NetSales + 30, 7)
Range("A4").Value = Mid(text, Cash + 30, 7)
Range("A5").Value = Mid(text, Card + 30, 7)
Range("A6").Value = Mid(text, HotDrinks + 30, 7)
Range("A7").Value = Mid(text, ColdDrinks + 30, 7)
Range("A8").Value = Mid(text, Sweets + 30, 7)
Range("A9").Value = Mid(text, Crisps + 30, 7)
Range("A10").Value = Mid(text, VAT - 9, 7)

Range("B2").Value = Mid(text, p + 1, 8)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as being able to choose a different file each time, you could use

```
with application.filedialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
'disallows the user from selecting more than one file at a time
.allowmultiselect=false
'shows the file open dialog box
.show

 if .selecteditems.count=0 then
 'dismisses dialog box if no selection
 else
 strPath=.selecteditems(1)
 end if
 end with
```

You can then use `strPath` to read the text from, though the way that I accomplished my reading from a text file was to write the text right to a hidden sheet in the workbook (make `text=textline` in your `Do Until EOF(1)` loop and add `[workbookname].sheet([sheetname]).cells(xrowx,1)=text` and `xrowx=xrowx+1` after that). The information is much more manageable in that format, rather than trying to read from one giant string.  Give that a whirl, see if it makes things easier for you.